# Ekstasi error bundling a package throwing JVM error

Tags: java, maven, cytoscape

I am trying to build a Cytoscape app using maven, and I am using EKZTAZI 5.0.1 . When I use Maven Package, it throws the following error :
Execution ekstazi of goal org.ekstazi:ekstazi-maven-plugin:5.0.1:select failed: Running with Java 9 requires -Djvm.options=jdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true

I have tried searching on how to pass this option online but I am unsure on how to. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It helps neither the user nor the reader  to simply downvote a question without giving insight into why. It is very plausible that my question is not well phrased or to the standards of stack exchange's community, but it is more helpful to give such an explanation on a down vote

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no Java 9 support available for the public release of Cytoscape, which is likely what is causing your issue.

The next major version release is in development and has Java 9 support (check the Cytoscape GitHub if you're interested in using this: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape)